# Stop/pause/disable 2 functions from a third

Tags: javascript

`myFunction1` is a mousewheel function and `myFunction2` is a keypress function. Both of them change a DIVs background-position when scrolling left/right. What I'm trying to do is when the window is all the way to either the left or right, that the changing of the background-position stops/pauses.

```
function myFunction1(){
   // do one thing
}

function myFunction2(){
  // do another thing
}
```

This I can do. It's this next part that's stumped me.

```
function myFunction3(){
  if(myFunction1 and myFunction2 == something){
    // stop/pause/disable myFunction1 and myFunction2
  }
}
```

I only want `myFunction1` and `myFunction2` to stop when either the far left or right is reached. Everywhere in between is business as usual.

Comment: Hey Qantas 94 Heavy, I'm that much of a noob, I'm not sure what you mean?

Comment: I dont understand what exactly you are trying to do, but why not use a boolean, check its value for true in function, set its value false when you dont need that function ?

Comment: Here's my actual code. I'm sure it's not pretty, but it will hopefully give you a better idea of what I'm trying to do.

Comment: `code
    (function($){
      $(document).scroll(function(){
        var current_left = $('html,body').offset().left;
        if ( current_left < 0 ){
          $("#tricycle").css('background-color', 'green');
        }
        if ( current_left == 0 ){
          $("#tricycle").css('background-color', 'red');
        }
        if ( current_left == '-' + $(window).width() * 5 ){
          $("#tricycle").css('background-color', 'red');
        }
      });
    })(jQuery);
code`

Instead of changing the background-color, I'd like to stop the 2 functions from working.

Comment: Sorry, think my comment formatting is lacking.

Comment: You should add this code in question, press edit and add.

Comment: Firstly I'd like to apologise that my posts, formatting, etc. are all over the place. Not only am I new to Javascript, but I'm also new to StackOverflow.
I've attempt also to make my very first JSFiddle (completely stripped back to bare basics) to try to help show what I have Frankensteined together and (almost) the effect I'm going for.
http://jsfiddle.net/SenorWombat/GFnZA/

Answer (score 0):

you should check in function1 AND in function2 if your div reached the the windows borders:

```
function whenWheelIsTurned() {
  if ( theDiveToMove.right >= window.rightBorder ) {
     return
  } else {
    theDivToMove.right += 5
  }
}
```

The actual .right property may vary on the library you are using.

Comment: Thanks superwese. It's not the detecting whether it's all the way to the left or right I'm having the trouble with. Thanks to clever folks at StackOverflow I was able to sort that out. It's the stopping of myFunction1 and 2 from changing the background-position of my DIV.

Comment: @Wombat: that's the general idea presented though - to check for the condition, then only do that if the condition of `myFunction3` is met.